# How to use TextFieldParser to read file in network?

Tags: asp.net, .net, textfieldparser

I am using `TextfieldParser` to iterate and read through a file. It works fine when the file is in my computer and I am doing tests, but the real file is in a network. I have the path, domain and password of the real file. The problem is an error is genarted stating that the File cannot be found. The path where it is being searched is ok.

Is `TextFieldParser` able to read a file on the network?

Thanx in advance

Comment: WHY ALL CAPS ? that's unnecessary.

Comment: Yes, of course. You have to open a stream to the file in the network. The parser just consumes it.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13919975/read-file-from-network-location-with-credentials-in-asp-net-code

Comment: If you read the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser(v=vs.110).aspx), you'll know the answer.