# Logging in to different domain using LogonUser API

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-logon

Calling LogonUser before a Winforms application starts running. So if the credentials are correct the application starts and if they are wrong the application wont start.

So this working fine with the user credentials for the domain my system belongs to. I was trying to make this work for a different user in a different domain by entering username in the format domain\username or username@domain. But its not working. Please suggest the right way to implement this.

Comment: are those domains joined? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/993418/logonuser-works-only-for-my-domain

Comment: What is the result of GetLastError?

Comment: No they are not joined. Getting wrong username or password as result of GetLastWin32Error.

Comment: Then without join/trust between the domains the domain controller you are talking to for authentication doesn't know anything about users of that other domain and will tell you so.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.